# WPML String translation

Tags: php, wordpress, wpml

i am really stacked,
i am trying to translate plugin using wpml, but strings are not in string translator, i tried to put strings in php, but i did something wrong and there is an error in syntax.

The problem is.
For example:

```
<?php echo ($is_open) ? 'Мы открыты, мы можем вас обслужить в данное время' : 'Мы закрыты, мы не можем вас обслужить в данное время' ?>
```

Wmpl do not recognize it as string.
I will appreciate any help.

[Full Code](http://freetexthost.com/fyiuaa44mk)

Answer (score 0):

For Wpml to pick up text for translation you will need to wrap the string in  __() function call. ie. _e('some text').

Take a look at the codex documentation here for internationalization: https://codex.wordpress.org/I18n_for_WordPress_Developers

Answer (score 0):

Didnt got it working with string translator,
but solved the problem.

Solution:
[Here is full code](http://freetexthost.com/5qkvvqbmry)